# How to I reshape the 2D array like this? (By using tensor)

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I want to resize my image from 32 * 32 to 16 * 16. (By using torch.tensor)
Like decreasing the resolution?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you want to change the number of elements total, it's a resize operation, not a reshape, see [the docs](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.Resize.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an image (stored in a tensor) and you want to decrease it's *resolution*, then you are not `reshaping` it, but rather *resizing* it.
To that end, you can use pytorch's [`interpolate`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.interpolate.html):

```py
import torch
from torch.nn import functional as nnf

y = nnf.interpolate(x[None, None, ...], size=(16, 16), mode='bicubic', align_corners=False, antialias=True)
```

Notes:

1. [`nnf.interpolate`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.interpolate.html) operates on *batches* of multi-channel images, that is, it expects its input `x` to have 4 dimensions: `batch`-`channels`-`height`-`width`. So, if your `x` is a single image with a single channel (e.g., an MNIST digit) you'll have to create a singleton batch dimension and a singleton channel dimension.
2. Pay close attention to `align_corners` and `antialias` -- make sure you are using the right configuration for your needs.

For more information regarding aliasing and alignment when resizing images you can look at [ResizeRight](https://github.com/assafshocher/ResizeRight).

Answer (score 0):

you can use resize from torchvision transforms:

```
import torchvision.transform as T
T.Resize(16)(your_image)
```

you can also chain it to other transforms

```
preprocess = T.Compose([
   T.Resize(N),
   T.CenterCrop(N),
   T.ToTensor(),
   T.Normalize(
       mean=mean,
       std=std
   )
])
preprocess(your_image)
```